# Can't run shared library compiled on Ubuntu on Mac

Tags: python, c, macos, ubuntu, ctypes

I compiled a cpp file on the ubuntu machine and generated the linker using the following commands:

```
g++ -c -fPIC foo.cpp -o foo.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so -o libfoo.so  foo.o
```

Then I loaded the libfoo.so linker file in python like below.

```
from ctypes import *
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./lib/cppFunctions/libfoo.so')
```

Then I can use the functions inside the cpp file with python on the ubuntu.

however, when I try to load .so file (libfoo.so) it on my mac, I 
get the following error.

```
OSError: dlopen(./lib/cppFunctions/libfoo.so, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    ./lib/cppFunctions/libfoo.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00
```

Full Error:

```
File "Resume.py", line 7, in <module>
    from PhraseRecommender import *
  File "/Users/aerin/Documents/bitbucket_BYOR/PhraseRecommender.py", line 4, in <module>
    from SingleSentenceRecord import * #TODO: What is the right way to import.
  File "/Users/aerin/Documents/bitbucket_BYOR/SingleSentenceRecord.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ByorFunctions import *
  File "/Users/aerin/Documents/bitbucket_BYOR/ByorFunctions.py", line 29, in <module>
    lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./lib/cppFunctions/libfoo.so')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(./lib/cppFunctions/libfoo.so, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    ./lib/cppFunctions/libfoo.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00
```

How can I make .so file run on mac?

Comment: Compile it on the Mac so it adheres to the Mach-O object file format.

Comment: You have to compile it on OS X. The executable formats for OS X and Linux are different.